# Internal group member cannot access teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I am completely stuck on this one!

I have a teams site within which I have added a group. They are all members of my org and are internal users.

Only one internal member is unable to access the site. All the others are perfectly able to use the site.

I have tried:

1. To check the permissions
2. No other user is impacted by this problem
3. I am trying to share internally
4. By copying and pasting the root URL to the teams site as the impacted user, I am presented with 'access denied'; But if trying a URL that is further along than the root folder (documents folder) user is able to see an empty folder (the folder should be full)
5. I have checked all the licenses and apps are correct
6. It is a teams site I am trying to get the user onto
7. I tried to directly share a file from within the site to the user but nothing happened.
8. Deleted the user from the group and then tried to add them again.

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direction you could have a look.

To allow custom script on a particular site (previously called "site collection"), follow these steps:

1.Download the latest SharePoint Online Management Shell.

2.Connect to SharePoint as a global admin or SharePoint admin in Microsoft 365. To learn how, see Getting started with SharePoint Online Management Shell.

3.Run the following command:

```
Set-SPOSite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Reference: [Allow or prevent custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script)